# add data attribute to jquery ui datepicker on initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, custom-data-attribute

I am initializing jquery ui's datepicker as follows:

```
var datesArray=['3/7/2016','3/12/2016']
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var theday = (date.getMonth()+1) +'/'+ 
            date.getDate()+ '/' + 
            date.getFullYear();
        return [true,$.inArray(theday, datesArray) >=0 ? "specialDate":''];
    }
});
```

This creates the calendar with the class `specialDate` applied to all dates in `datesArray`.

Additionally, I need to add a unique data attribute value (something like `data-value="39"`) to these same dates on initialization of the datepicker, but I am not sure how to select the dates.

I can use something like

```
var datavalues = {
    "3/7/2016" : "38",
    "3/12/2016" : "39"
};
```

where `38` and `39` are the `data-value`s.

This question about [adding a custom parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580236/add-custom-parameter-to-jquery-ui-datepicker) gets me close, but I'm not sure exactly how to use this to just add the data attributes on creation.

Comment: There's no out-of-the-box way to do this. The shortest way would be to use `onChangeMonthYear`, but it would still be pretty cumbersome and/or fragile. What're you trying to achieve? I'm fairly sure there're better ways than constantly binding and unbinding data

Comment: @blgt remember, though, I'm basically trying to populate the calendar with a datalayer. I'm sure I can do some goofy thing immediately after creating the calendar, but I'd much rather add the data attributes as the calendar is created, sort of like how that class is being applied.

Comment: That's a re-statement of the question. Could you provide more details about *what you're trying to achieve* with the additional data? (also, relevant info could be edited into the question instead of a comment, for the better formatting)

Comment: When a date is selected, I want to use data that's associated with that date with js.

Comment: @adamrowe This will not be possible to do *as the calendar is created*. The class is added using 'beforeShow`, which is similar to `onSelect`, but it still requires user interaction, or an event to trigger the function.

Comment: @adamrowe using `.date()` for this will not be a good way to go. We need more information about what you're trying to accomplish to be able to help.

Comment: @adamrowe You could bind the full [date-data] array against the relevant input and use `onSelect` to pick the one you need, when you need it. Or not bother binding it at all, just keep it as an in-memory variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with `.data()` or as a data attribute when the datepicker is created. You can use `onSelect` like so:

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ha5zgvby/

**HTML**

```
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</p>
<p>Stuff:
  <input type="text" id="special" />
</p>
```

**JQuery**

```
var datavalues = {
  "03/07/2016": "38",
  "03/12/2016": "39"
};
$(function() {
  var $result = $("#special");
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    onSelect: function(dt, obj) {
      $result.val(datavalues[dt]);
    },
    altField: "#result"
  });
});
```

When a date is picked, the function is passed the value that is selected. If that value is in your Object as an Index, then you can make use of it in some way.

Comment: @Twisty.. How can i display count of any number in datepicker's date?

Comment: @PathikVejani Not sure I understand the question. Do you mean show a count of days between a range of two dates?

Comment: @Twisty see this my qtn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625021/bind-custom-data-with-date-in-bootstrap-datepicker